# How do you read a multidimensional array out of clEnqueueReadBuffer?

Tags: opencl

I have 2D array C which I instantiate like this:

```
const int wA = 16;
float * C[wA];
for(int i = 0; i < hA; i++)
{
C[i] = new float[hA];
for(int i2 = 0; i2 < hA; i2++)
    C[i][i2] = 0;
}

/* looks like this:
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
*/
```

I create a kernel which operates on C:

```
__kernel void simpleMultiply(__global float* outputC, 
                            int widthA, 
                            int heightA, 
                            int widthB, 
                            int heightB, 
                            __global float * inputA, 
                            __global float * inputB)
{
    int row = get_global_id(1);
    int col = get_global_id(0);
    float sum = 0.0f;
    for(int i = 0; i < widthA; i++)
    {
        sum += inputA[row*widthA+i] * inputB[i*widthB+col];
    }
    outputC[row*widthB+col] = sum;
}
```

and everything goes fine. I get CL_SUCCESS for status all the way through from setting up the context to creating the buffers, creating the kernel, program, clEnqueueNDRangeKernel,  clEnqueueReadBuffer, etc.

But when I go to read the output it crashes.

```
status = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cmdQueue, kernel, 2, NULL, globalws, localws, 0, NULL, NULL);
cout << "\nclEnqueueNDRangeKernel: " << (status == CL_SUCCESS ? "SUCCESS" : "FAIL"); // prints SUCCESS
status = clEnqueueReadBuffer(cmdQueue, bufferC, CL_TRUE, 0, wC*hC*sizeof(float), (void*)C, 0, NULL, NULL);
cout << "\nclEnqueueReadBuffer: " << (status == CL_SUCCESS ? "SUCCESS" : "FAIL"); // prints SUCCESS
cout << "\nC[0][0]: " << C[0][0]; // <--crash
```

[image]

I am just as new to C++ as I am OpenCL so this could be due to a weak understanding of arrays and pointers in c++.

The whole code is [here](http://pastebin.com/NkiCam7Z)

Comment: Are you sure that line 67 is a blocking-read? Maybe you are cout-ing in line 69 before it finishes reading . Also your C is array of pointers so dimension of each element may not be known? Can you try with pure 2D array and pure double-pointer?

Comment: The third argument on line 67 says to make it blocking. So it is blocking for sure. It will take me a day or so until I get the time to redo the arrays (im new to c++).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array

```
float * C[wA];
```

Is a  1D array of `float *` pointers. So you haven't created, in memory, a 2D array  with contiguous rows and columns. But you've created an array of pointers to rows.

So you should  flatten on the host array C  and index into it the same way as you do on the kernel.

```
float * C;

c = new float[ha * ha]; // Create a  contiguous memory area  to be addressed  in a 2D pattern

memset( C, 0, ha * ha  * sizeof(float) ); // Set all bytes to zero


...
```

Now  you can  address  the C array   after running the kernel

```
cout << C[ icolumn  + irow * ha ];  // icolumn and irow are your row and columns indices
```